# What is the relationship of the lengths of the two primes in an RSA composite to the square root of the composite?

Tags: cryptography

I’m a newbie playing with ideas for factoring RSA type composites using the assumption that all primes are of the form (6*n +/- 1) in a “while” loop.
My code is working fine but, for efficiency sake, I need to know where to set the
limits of the loop. If the square root of the composite is always greater than the
smallest prime, I can index down from the square root more efficiently than indexing up from n = 1. I’m a long retired engineer trying to keep my brain alive so please go easy, folks. Thanks!

My question above is specifically about the nature of RSA type composites.  I can
Post the script if would be useful to the community but the question stands alone.

Comment: It is easy to show that the smallest prime must be smaller than the square root of the product of the two primes. Practical RSA moduli are too large to factor by looping over all primes of the form 6n +/- 1.

Comment: Just for grins, my factor approach takes about  88 million cycles to find the smallest factor of a 20 digit composite formed by the product of 2 random 33 bit primes.  I have no idea how that compares to a more sophisticated approach.